# Can you export a loaded (dynamic) assembly into a dll/exe file?

Tags: c#, export, .net-assembly

Title says it all.

Is there a way to export a loaded (dynamic) assembly, in the appDomain, into a dll/exe file, and keep all its code intact?

Comment: "*Title says it all.*" it doesn't actually, do you mean dump running code into another library to be used later? whats the use-case here

Comment: If it's a dynamic assembly you should be able to use `AssemblyBuilder.Save`. Otherwise you should be able to enumerate the modules which make up the assembly.

Comment: @TheGeneral pretty much, i just found a program which dynamically loads a assembly and wanted to dump it to see what type of classes/functions it has.
@Ben Thanks for letting me know about `AssemblyBuilder.Save`, didn't specify that it was a dynamic assembly, thought exporting worked the same for both dynamic and non-dynamic.